# How to call variables in controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use `Auth::user()->id;` and post them with another model under `'user_id`' so I don't have to manually give users a `'user_id'`.

I've checked and included the required files and I'm getting the users `"id"`  from **Users Table**

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
echo $user_id; //this is returning right user "id"
```

I'm having trouble calling variables and posting it to DB in controller functions any help would be fine.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token1' => 'required',
            'token2' => 'required'
        ]);
        $tokens = new Tokens([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'token1' => $request->get('token1'),
            'token2' => $request->get('token2')
        ]);
        $tokens->save();
        return view('/home');
    }
```

Post the User `"id"` from **User table** into Tokens table's `"user_id"` so I can work with models

Getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: tokens.user_id (SQL: insert into "tokens"
>   ("token1", "token2", "updated_at", "created_at") values (asddsadf,
>   sdfasdf, 2019-09-24 11:53:57, 2019-09-24 11:53:57))

My migration is:

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->string('token1');
    $table->string('token2');
    $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: what is the trouble here ? you gettin any errors?

Comment: updated thread with error

Comment: I think the field `user_id` is not fillable in your model, look at your model and `$fillables` array

Comment: update your question with `Tokens` model code.

Comment: solved thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid filling the user_id in this way.

The error is thrown because `user_id` is not a [fillable property](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment). But the correct way to handle this is with the [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships).

So I suppose that `Tokens` has a `belongsTo` relation because of its `user_id` foreign key (that anyway should be an `unsignedInteger` column) and in your model you have something like:

```php
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class) 
}
```

If you have a look at the [offical documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) you will see that you should change your code in this way:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'token1' => 'required',
            'token2' => 'required'
        ]);

$tokens = new Tokens([
            // 'user_id' => $user_id, This is useless
            'token1' => $request->get('token1'),
            'token2' => $request->get('token2')
        ]);

        // With this method you're going to set the user_id column
        $token->user()->associate(auth()->user());

        $tokens->save();

        return view('/home');
    }
```

Comment: yeah thank with my code problem was in **model** i made it an fillable property now everything works fine. will it fill the proper user ID in user_id with your method? so i won't need to fill user_id?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the relationship documentation... Setting a foreign key with a fillable property **it's not a good practice at all**. It may cause a lot of problems... expecially if you fill it with an unexisting ID... That's why you should use Laravel's relationship. Also, with this method, the relation is available in your model from the creation, instead of performing a lazy load after the creation